# How can I get the 20 largest words frequency?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two dictionary. Each of dictionary include words. Some words are common some are not. I want to show to output common word frequency1 frequency2 and frequency sum. How can I do that ? And I have to find the top 20.I need to find the 20 largest frequency from big to small. How can I do that ? It gives all the words in this list. I only want 20 words. How can I print?

```
For example my output must be like:`
Common WORD frequ1. freq2 freqsum
1 print      10.     5.      15
2 number.     2.     1.       3. 
3 program.    19.   20.    39.
```

`

```
def countwords(lst):
dct = {}
for word in lst:
    dct[word] = dct.get(word, 0) + 1
return dct


count1 = countwords(finallist1)
count2 = countwords(finallist2)

words1 = set(count1.keys())
words2 = set(count2.keys())

common_words = words1.intersection(words2)
for w in common_words:
print(f"{w}\t{count1[w]}\t{count2[w]}\t{count1[w] + count2[w]}")
```

Comment: This is obviously an exercise, so will not write it for you and only give you a hint to think about a dictionary where the key is a word and the value is the number of times the word has been found.

Comment: I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 0):

actually your program is very close, just need to address 2 problems + `reformatting`.  Please see the notes in the code:
(you can refine the print label as you like -it's straightforward.)

```
finallist1 = 'Program is fun Program is tough program is fun and tough'
finallist2 = 'Program is number one game program need to be fun and tough'


def count_words(lst):
    dct = {}

    for word in lst.split():       # need to split to get words
        dct[word] = dct.get(word, 0) + 1
    return dct



if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    count1 = count_words(finallist1)
    count2 = count_words(finallist2)
    print(f' dict1: {count1} ')
    print(f' dict2: {count2} ')

    words1 = set(count1.keys())
    words2 = set(count2.keys())

    common_words = words1.intersection(words2)
    
    for i, w in enumerate(common_words, 1):    # enumerate() to get index, word
        print(f"{i}\t{w}\t{count1[w]}\t{count2[w]}\t{count1[w] + count2[w]}")
```

Comment: That output doesn't seem to match what you have in the code. The word `tough` would be `tough,` because you are using `split()` and the default delimiter is a space. Isn't right?

Comment: My bad -2nd edit cut-n-past miss it.  Thanks, correct it now. (good catch)

Comment: you should do `replace ([',.'],'')` to eliminate all the `.` and `,` from the sentence. That way you can get the best results